# Hibernate throws org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

Tags: hibernate, exception, jboss7.x, h2, h2db

I am using JBoss AS 7 with H2 database.
I have a standalone application that tries to connect to this database like this.

My config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="Test">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem:test</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
  <mapping class="Kunde" resource="Kunde.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping class="Mitarbeiter" resource="Mitarbeiter.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My mapping files are:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Oct 26, 2012 7:34:15 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Kunde" table="KUNDE">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="vorname" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="VORNAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="nachname" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NACHNAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="firma" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="FIRMA" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Oct 26, 2012 7:34:15 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Mitarbeiter" table="MITARBEITER">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="vorname" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="VORNAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="nachname" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NACHNAME" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My entity classes:

```
public class Kunde {
    long id;
    String vorname;
    String nachname;
    String firma;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getVorname() {
        return vorname;
    }

    public void setVorname(String vorname) {
        this.vorname = vorname;
    }

    public String getNachname() {
        return nachname;
    }

    public void setNachname(String nachname) {
        this.nachname = nachname;
    }

    public String getFirma() {
        return firma;
    }

    public void setFirma(String firma) {
        this.firma = firma;
    }
}
```

(The other one looks similar).

My test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // This step will read hibernate.cfg.xml and prepare hibernate for
        // use
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                .buildServiceRegistry();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration
                .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        // Create new instance of Kinde and set values in it by reading them
        // from form object
        System.out.println("Inserting Record");
        Kunde kunde = new Kunde();
        kunde.setId(1);
        kunde.setVorname("A");
        kunde.setNachname("N");
        kunde.setFirma("Privat");
        session.save(kunde);
        System.out.println("Done");

        // Actual insertion will happen at this step
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:45 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:45 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final}
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:45 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:45 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:45 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:45 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:45 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Kunde.hbm.xml
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:45 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Mitarbeiter.hbm.xml
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:45 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: Test
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:45 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:45 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:45 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:45 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [org.h2.Driver] at URL [jdbc:h2:mem:test]
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:45 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {}
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:46 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:46 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:46 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Okt 26, 2012 7:56:46 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
```

Any idea?

---

Update:

Stupid me :)

I printed the entire stack trace which revealed that my classpath was incomplete:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.util.proxy.MethodFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more
```

I added the javaassist JAR and it is working fine now.

Sorry.

Comment: +1 feel free to add the edit as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to use javassistjar file; I used javassist-3.10.0.GA.jar and this error gone